# MAUI 8 - How to change Popup background overlay color?

Tags: xaml, popup, maui, winui

With MAUI 7.0 next code allows to change Popup background overlay color, but that code doesn't work on MAUI 8.0

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
    x:Class="TestMaui8.WinUI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:maui="using:Microsoft.Maui"
    xmlns:local="using:TestMaui8.WinUI">
    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="SystemAltMediumColor">Transparent</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" Color="{StaticResource SystemAltMediumColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentDialogBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="{StaticResource SystemAltMediumColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentDialogDimmingThemeBrush" Color="{StaticResource SystemAltMediumColor}" />
        <StaticResource x:Key="ContentDialogBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" />
        <StaticResource x:Key="PopupLightDismissOverlayBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" />

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SliderBorderBrush" Color="#1A73E8" />
        <Style TargetType="Slider">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SliderBorderBrush}"/>
        </Style>
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```

Does anybody know why it didn't work and how to fix it?

Updated to add some images

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use Community Toolkit Popup?

Comment: Yes... I'm using Popup from Community Toolkit Popup

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You may see the source code here : [CommunityToolkit Popup](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/02896d32571af05ede9df8d6b10b32db174e15f6/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core/Handlers/Popup/PopUpHandler.windows.cs#L147). The overlay color has been set to a fixed color. So there should be no direct way to change it **even using the code you post.**

Again we commend you raise a feature request for changing the overlay color on [CommunityToolkit GitHub Page](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues).

The workaround I post below does not work for a 'Transparent' color.

---

CommunityToolkit Popup does not have Overlay color feature. You could raise a feature request for it on [CommunityToolkit GitHub Page](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues).

Yes, the above code you post used to work but it doesn't work for .NET8 with the newest CommunityToolkit.Maui nuget.

But if you want to change the overlay color, here is a workaround.

Set the Color of the Popup to the color you want. And make the ContentView in it to be full screen size.

```
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             ...
             Color="Black"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             >
    //make the size to be the full screen size
    <ContentView WidthRequest="1920" HeightRequest="1080">
        <VerticalStackLayout WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300" BackgroundColor="Green">
            <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png"/>
            <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ContentView>
</toolkit:Popup>
```